# For any two sets , the power sets : $\mathcal P(A\setminus B) = \mathcal P(A) \setminus \mathcal P(B)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

For any two sets , the power sets : $\mathcal P(A\setminus B) = \mathcal P(A) \setminus \mathcal P(B)$?

Is this proof correct?

$$\begin{split}x \in \mathcal P(A\setminus B) &\iff x \subseteq A\setminus B  \\ &\iff x \subseteq A \land x \nsubseteq B \\ & \iff x \in\mathcal P(A) \land x \notin \mathcal P(B) \\ & \iff x \in \mathcal P(A) \setminus \mathcal P(B)\end{split}$$

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Consider $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1\}$. Then $\{1,2\}\in P(A)\setminus P(B)$.

Comment: How did you get from the second line to the third line?

Comment: No.  That proves proves $P(A\\B)\subset P (A)\\P (B)$.  It doesn't prove $P (A)\\P (B)\subset P (A\\B) $.  Which is not true.

Comment: I think you didnvt mean $\subsetneq $ (which means *is* a proper (unequal) subset.  I think you meant $\not \subset $ which means not a subset.... any way P (A)\P (B) does not equal P (A)\P (B) although it is a subset.

Comment: @fleablood Actually, $P(A\setminus B)\subseteq P(A)\setminus P(B)$ never holds (because $P(A\setminus B)\setminus(P(A)\setminus P(B))\ni \emptyset$). $P(A)\setminus P(B)\subseteq P(A\setminus B)$ holds if and only if either $B\supseteq A$ or $B\cap A=\emptyset$.

Comment: You sure? If A={1,2,3} and B={3,4} then P (A\B) =P ({1,2}) and P (A)\P (B)=P (A\B) $\cup $ subsets of A containing 3 and one of 1 or 2 = P (A)\{{3}} $

Comment: The error is on line 2 of the argument. Instead of $x\not\subseteq B$, you should have $x\cap B=\emptyset$. In other words, _all_, not just _some_, elements of $x$ are not in $B$.

Comment: Oops.  Forgot about the empty set.  The empty set is of course a subset of A\B and of B so that throws even the subset half off the rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the case that:
$$
x \subseteq A \setminus B \iff x \subseteq A \land x \not\subseteq B
$$

Indeed, the statement you're trying to prove is actually false. For a counterexample, consider $A = \{1, 2\}$ and $B = \{2, 3\}$. Notice that:
$$
P(A \setminus B) = P(\{1\}) = \{\varnothing, \{1\}\}
$$
while on the other hand:
$$
P(A) \setminus P(B) = \{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\} \setminus \{\varnothing, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{2, 3\}\} = \{\{1\}, \{1, 2\}\}
$$

Comment: I assumed the OP meant $x \not \subset B$, not $x\subsetneq B $.  In context it makes sense.

Comment: @Adriano Why doesn't $x \subseteq A \setminus B \iff x \subseteq A \land x \not \subseteq B$ work?

Comment: Its not an equivalence.  Consider $A=\{1,2,3\}, B=\{2,3,4\}, x=\{1,2\}$.  Now since $A\setminus B=\{1\}$ it is clear that we have $x\subseteq A\wedge x\nsubseteq B$ but we do **not** have $x\subseteq A\setminus B$.

Answer (score 2):

This proof can't be right, because, say, if $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{1, 2\}$, then $P(A - B) = P(\varnothing) = \{\varnothing\}$. Meanwhile, $P(A) - P(B) = \{\varnothing, \{1\}\} - \{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\} = \varnothing$.

Comment: Along those lines, one could prove that actually $P(A\setminus B)=P(A)\setminus P(B)$ can never hold, because $\emptyset\in RHS\setminus LHS$.

Answer (score 1):

Inclusion does not hold in either direction.

$\mathcal P(A\setminus B)\subseteq\mathcal P(A)\setminus\mathcal P(B)$ is always false, because $\emptyset\in\mathcal P(A\setminus B)$ while $\emptyset\notin\mathcal P(A)\setminus\mathcal P(B).$

$\mathcal P(A)\setminus\mathcal P(B)\subseteq\mathcal P(
A\setminus B)$ is sometimes false: if $x\in A\cap B$ and $y\in A\setminus B,$ then $\{x,y\}\in\mathcal P(A)\setminus\mathcal P(B)$ while $\{x,y\}\notin\mathcal P(A\setminus B);$
in fact, $\mathcal P(A)\setminus\mathcal P(B)\subseteq\mathcal P(
A\setminus B)$ holds only when $A\subseteq B$ or $A\cap B=\emptyset.$